# check any match in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
a1 = {1,3,5,7,9};
a2 = {2,4,6,8,9};
```

In both the arrays, there is a common value 9. I would like to know if there is a built in php function present which returns true or false if at least one value matches or not.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `array_intersect()`

Comment: As you mention this is json

    $a1 = {1,3,5,7,9};
    $a2 = {2,4,6,8,9};
    
    $array1 = json_decode($a1, true);
    $array2 = json_decode($a2, true);
    
    array_intersect($array1,$array2) ? true : false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$a1 = [1,3,5,7,9];
$a2 = [2,4,6,8,9];
$a3 = [10];

array_intersect($a1,$a2) ? true : false;
// => true

array_intersect($a1,$a3) ? true : false;
// => false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_intersect` function in PHP. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

**Example**

```
$a = array(1, 3, 5, 7);
$b = array(1, 2, 3, 4);



$haveMatch =  (array_intersect($a, $b))?true:false;
echo $haveMatch;
```